# downloading file from S3 using boto3 key error

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download a joblib file from S3 but getting errors with the key format..

This is my S3 path to the file:

```
"s3://v1/v2/v3/v4/model.joblib"
```

This is my code:

```
import boto3
bucketname = "v1" 
key = "v2/v3/v4"
filename = "model.joblib"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucketname, key)
body = obj.get()['label_model.joblib'].read()
```

ultimately i want to be able to do:

```
from joblib import load

model = load("model.joblib")
```

Error i got:

```
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

Comment: Looks like you have never appended the file name to the key value.

Comment: In Amazon s3, the `key` of an object includes the full path and name. Therefore, you should use: `key = 'v1/v2/v3/v4/model.joblib'`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the file without the filename.

Your code is:

```
import boto3
bucketname = "v1" 
key = "v2/v3/v4"
filename = "model.joblib"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucketname, key)
body = obj.get()['label_model.joblib'].read()
```

But you need to add the filename to the key variable. Here is an example downloading the file from s3:

```
bucketname = "v1"
key = "v2/v3/v4"
filename = "model.joblib"

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)

with open('filename', 'wb') as f:
    bucket.download_fileobj(f'{key}/{filename}', f)
```